# Inconsistent overload resolution for Action and Func

Tags: c#

Consider the following example:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo(() => { });
        Foo(() => { throw new Exception(); });
        Foo(() => { Throws(); });
        Foo(() => { throw new Exception(); return; });
        Foo(() => { throw new Exception(); return true; });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Foo(Action a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(Action)");
    }

    public static void Foo(Func<bool> f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(Func<bool>)");
    }

    public static void Throws()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Which has the following output:

```
Foo(Action)
Foo(Func<bool>)
Foo(Action)
Foo(Action)
Foo(Func<bool>)
```

I was quite surprised to notice that `Foo(() => { throw new Exception(); });` invokes the `Foo(Func<bool> f)` overload. I would expect it to invoke the other overload. Also notice that `Foo(() => { throw new Exception(); return; });` invokes `Foo(Action a)`.

This behavior seems inconsistent. I cannot find the reason for this. It appears that when the compiler detects that the lambda always throws it will favor the `Foo(Func<bool> f)` overload, however adding a return statement that never will be reached, will change the behavior. Why does it behave like this?

Comment: If you try any function with a return value and just add a Throw new Exception(); without anything else you can see the compiler does not complain about missing return, so this is the correct behavior even if it seems it's not (what I have no clue is which type of return object will use, maybe object?).

Comment: Methods with `while(true)`, `throw new Exception` are compatible to delegates with any return type. Refer the linked duplicate for more info.